# React: Force complete update of component

Tags: reactjs

I have a component that I have written (it is a list). When the component is updated (this list is changed), the onclick event does not update and passes the same values as before the component was rendered. Is there a way to force React to update the entire div from scratch? The variable "value.edit_title_normal" does change, just not the onclick event.

***I have removed some excess code for brevity ***

```
class SearchResults extends React.PureComponent {
    //Code to show the detailed information
    render() {
        //Individual record
        const startItem = (this.props.itemsPerPage * this.props.page) - this.props.itemsPerPage;
        const endItem = startItem + this.props.itemsPerPage;
        //Slice is from/to
        let all = searchableDatabase.slice(startItem, endItem).map((value, index) => {
            return (
                <div onClick={(e) => this.showDetailedInfo(index, e)} > // <== This bit here is not updating when  re-rendered
                    {value.edit_title_normal}
                </div>
            )
        });

        //Main container
        return (
            <div>
                <div>
                    <Pagination allLength={searchableDatabase.length} page={this.props.page} itemsPerPage={this.props.itemsPerPage} />
                </div>

                <div>
                    {all}
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've misdiagnosed the problem. The index in the map callback always  starts from zero, so it's impossible for it to ever change to something else. You're operating on a new array sliced from the original and the map method doesn't know or care about the original array's indexes.

I assume that you expect the index to start from `startItem` instead of 0. Then you'll have to add it manually to the index:

```html
<div onClick={(e) => this.showDetailedInfo(index + startItem, e)} >
```